# How to extend a logical volume using Powershell

Tags: windows-xp, remote, powershell, logical-drive, wmi

On Windows XP SP3, how can I extend a volume using Powershell on a remote computer?

I prefer WMI over Powershell remoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my local computer I would do this by piping the commands to diskpart:

```
PS> $a = "select disk 0","select volume 0","extend" | diskpart
PS> write-host $a
```

Maybe you can build on this to achieve the desired result on the remote computer

Comment: Current solution:
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $compName -Credential $compCred -ScriptBlock {"rescan","select volume 2","extend" | diskpart}

Answer (score 0):

```
$pass = convertto-securestring "p@$$w0rd" -asplaintext -force

$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "10.10.10.10\Administrator",$pass

Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.10.10.10 -Credential $myCred -ScriptBlock {"rescan","select volume 2","extend" | diskpart}
```

______________________________________________________________________________-

Where 10.10.10.10 is the remote host where we need to run the `Get-PSRemoting` command.